# Switch between language with button in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to create a `Quarto` document with a button to switch between two languages. I would like to have a button like to one to switch between themes in the right top. Here I created some simple code:

````
---
title: "Change between languages with a button"
theme:
  light: flatly
  dark: darkly
---

# Example

This is just some example text which could be switch to a different language using a button like the one for themes.

```{r}
print("Hello world!")
```
````

Output:

[image]

I feel like there should be an option to switch maybe between two documents by a button or specify parts of text in your `.qmd` file that could be changed by a button. Unfortunately, I haven't found any useful code to achieve this so I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: Hi @Quinten - I don't know the answer, but have seen [babelquarto](https://github.com/ropensci-review-tools/babelquarto)?

Comment: Hi @Ben, Thanks for your comment! This looks really promising and I am going to check that out.